# How to import large XML/JSON dataset into Django/Postgres app/database?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, heroku

We have a large Filemaker database that and have written a tool that exports all the required information into XML/JSON.

We've created a Django App with the Django REST Framework and set up our model appopriately, but are now a bit confused about the best way to import all our XML/JSON data into the site.

Initially, we modified the Filemaker output to match the structure of `dumpdata` and thought a fixture combined with `loaddata` would be ideal but the more I read, it seems impossible due to the eventual size of the file and memory issues (We are hosting our app on a heroku dev instance at the moment).

Can anyone recommend the best way to go about loading this data set into our Django app? (We could also write a script to insert everything one-by-one via the API, but that also seems incredibly inefficient).

Our JSON structure is, for example, as follows, if it is important:

```
[
    {
        "model": "archive.archiveobject",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "title": "Example Title",
            "description": "Example Description",
            "date_begin": "2014-03-12",
            "date_end": "2014-03-12",
            "created": "2014-04-01T14:04:53.496Z",
            "owner": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other things you should consider:

- Heroku has a time limit on requests, so your application will need to send an HTTP response fairly soon after receiving the request.
- You will probably want loading to be robust in the event of a transient failure, so you'll need a way to mark objects as loaded and resume from where you left off.

My recommendation would be that you divide the job into chunks (perhaps 100 objects and go up from there) and create a bulk loading API call that you can use to load these chunks. A quick and dirty solution might be putting the chunks into separate files (chunk-0000001.json) and renaming upon completion (loaded-chunk-0000001.json). File-level locking on these files would allow you to run the job concurrently.